# How to add two huge number with assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bigint

I'm a very newbie at Assembly Language. And I don't know how to add 2 huge number input from keyboard. The code below show the way to add 2 number but I want to input from keyboard, and that 2 number with max 10 digits, so how can i do this? Anyone can help me?

```
name "huge"
org     100h
jmp     code
len     equ     32
; first number is: 423454612361234512344535179521
num1    db      0,0,4,2,3,4,5,4,6,1,2,3,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,4,5,3,5,1,7,9,5,2,1                                                 
; second number is: 712378847771981123513137882498
num2    db      0,0,7,1,2,3,7,8,8,4,7,7,7,1,9,8,1,1,2,3,5,1,3,1,3,7,8,8,2,4,9,8
sum     db      len dup(0) ; declare array to keep the result.

code:   nop ; entry point (nop does nothing, it's nope).
    xor     bx, bx
    mov     cx, len 
    mov     bx, len-1  ; point to lest significant digit!
        
next_digit:

        ; add digits:
        mov     al, num1[bx]
        adc     al, num2[bx]
        aaa
        mov     sum[bx], al
        dec     bx        
        loop    next_digit

adc     sum[bx], 0
mov     cx, len
mov     bx, 0

print_d:
        mov     al, sum[bx]
        or      al, 30h
        mov     ah, 0eh
        int     10h        
        inc     bx
        loop    print_d        
mov ah, 0
int 16h

ret
```

Comment: So you already have code to do the adding, and you just need to know how to read input into an array of decimal digits?  Seems pretty straightforward, just read an ASCII string and mask off the high bits of each digit, or subtract `'0'`

Comment: thanks for your advise, it's working!!! ^^

Comment: There is no [tag:bcd] here.

Comment: @user207421: Instructions like [`aaa`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aaa) are often described as working with "unpacked BCD", and work similarly to true BCD instructions like [`daa`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/daa).  It's true that inefficient base-10 bigint isn't exactly the same thing as BCD, though, since there's no packing an unpacking, so I'm not going to re-add the tag.